# Invalid path on windows

Tags: python-3.x, path

I am setup the report path on win10, using `Path` method to create file path

```
from os.path import dirname,abspath
from pathlib import Path

base_dir = dirname(abspath(__file__))
now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
test_reports_address = Path(base_dir, 'report')
if not os.path.exists(test_reports_address):
    os.mkdir(test_reports_address)
filepath = Path(test_reports_address, now + "_report.html")
fp = open(filepath, 'wb')
```

But it got exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1438, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/workspace/pis/run.py", line 30, in <module>
    fp = open(filepath, 'wb')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\workspace\\pis\\report\\2020-07-20-14:45:08_report.html'
```

I think i use the correct `\\` to present the file path on windows, is there anything else i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows paths cant have certain characters in them. In this case you're trying to use `:` which is forbidden.

```
The following reserved characters:
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file